# How can I use Selenium (Python) to do a Google Search and then open the results of the first page in new tabs?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

As the title said, I'd like to performa a Google Search using Selenium and then open all results of the first page on separate tabs.

Please have a look at the code, I can't get any further (it's just my 3rd day learning Python)

Thank you for your help !!

### Code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pyautogui

query = 'New Search Query'

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/Desktop-Files/Chromedriver/chromedriver')
browser.get('http://www.google.com')

search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys(query)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('LC20lb')

element.click()
```

The reason why I imported pyautogui is because I tried simulating a right click and then open in new tab for each result but it was a little confusing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about `pyautogui` as what you want to do can be done in Selenium. Same with most of the rest. You just do not need it. See if this code meets your needs.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

query = 'sins of a solar empire' #my query about a video game
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')

search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys(query)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

links = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('r') #I went on Google Search and found the container class for the link

for link in links:
    url = link.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute("href") #this code extracts the url of the HTML link
    browser.execute_script('''window.open("{}","_blank");'''.format(url)) # this code uses Javascript to open a new tab and open the given url in that new tab
    print(link.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  This worked perfectly. Is there a chance of getting in trouble as in my IP blocked from google if i use this ? Or how does it work?

Comment: @Nas24 pass me an upvote too :). Whether you might get in trouble depends on how you use this. This program by itself shouldn't get you in trouble. If you add the capability to go to other pages and spam the query robotically, there is a good chance you will need to enter Captchas to use Google search.